# How to programmatically create multiple CMS pages at once?

Tags: magento2, cms, programmatically, cms-pages

I am working in Magento 2 and I am needing to create multiple CMS pages all at one time. I am trying to set up an Install script to do this all at once. Every tutorial and search that I look up shows how to create **one** CMS page programmatically but I've searched everywhere and haven't found a single one showing how to create multiple at the same time. Is this even possible?

I have created a custom module with an InstallData script that looks like this:

```
namespace <VendorName>\<ModuleName>\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
    private $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $page = $this->_pageFactory->create();

        $page1 = $page->load('page1', 'identifier');
        if ($page1->getId()) {
            $page1->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')->save();
        } else {
            $page->setTitle('Page 1')
                ->setIdentifier('page1')
                ->setIsActive(true)
                ->setPageLayout('1column')
                ->setStores(array(0))
                ->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')
                ->save();
        }

        $page2 = $page->load('page2', 'identifier');
        if ($page2->getId()) {
            $page2->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')->save();
        } else {
            $page->setTitle('Page 2')
                ->setIdentifier('page2')
                ->setIsActive(true)
                ->setPageLayout('1column')
                ->setStores(array(0))
                ->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')
                ->save();
        }

        $page3 = $page->load('page3', 'identifier');
        if ($page3->getId()) {
            $page3->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')->save();
        } else {
            $page->setTitle('Page 3')
                ->setIdentifier('page3')
                ->setIsActive(true)
                ->setPageLayout('1column')
                ->setStores(array(0))
                ->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')
                ->save();
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

This does not throw any errors, but when I enable the module it only creates the first page 'page1' and doesn't create any of the others. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something pretty similar to DavidVR's answer, except the else statements in his answer have the wrong page variable.

My solution:

```
namespace <VendorName>\<ModuleName>\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface
{
    private $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(\Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup,
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ) {
        $setup->startSetup();

        $page1 = $this->_pageFactory->create();
        $page1->load('page1', 'identifier');
        if ($page1->getId()) {
            $page1->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')->save();
        } else {
            $page1->setTitle('Page 1')
                ->setIdentifier('page1')
                ->setIsActive(true)
                ->setPageLayout('1column')
                ->setStores(array(0))
                ->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')
                ->save();
        }

        $page2 = $this->_pageFactory->create();
        $page2->load('page2', 'identifier');
        if ($page2->getId()) {
            $page2->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')->save();
        } else {
            $page2->setTitle('Page 2')
                ->setIdentifier('page2')
                ->setIsActive(true)
                ->setPageLayout('1column')
                ->setStores(array(0))
                ->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')
                ->save();
        }

        $page3 = $this->_pageFactory->create();
        $page3->load('page3', 'identifier');
        if ($page3->getId()) {
            $page3->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')->save();
        } else {
            $page3->setTitle('Page 3')
                ->setIdentifier('page3')
                ->setIsActive(true)
                ->setPageLayout('1column')
                ->setStores(array(0))
                ->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')
                ->save();
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Identifier for each CMS page must be unique, you are using same identifier for each page.
So, change following code snippet;

```
 $page2 = $this->_pageFactory->create()->load('page2', 'identifier');
```

to

```
 $page2 = $this->_pageFactory->create()->load('page2', 'identifier2');
```

and do so for each page's code.

Comment: hi vivek, can you post your answer to this issue https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249369/product-edit-form-issue-in-admin-panel-magento2

Answer (score 0):

try changing to:

```
    $page1 = $$this->_pageFactory->create()->load('page1', 'identifier');
    if ($page1->getId()) {
        $page1->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')->save();
    } else {
        $page->setTitle('Page 1')
            ->setIdentifier('page1')
            ->setIsActive(true)
            ->setPageLayout('1column')
            ->setStores(array(0))
            ->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')
            ->save();
    }

    $page2 = $this->_pageFactory->create()->load('page2', 'identifier');
    if ($page2->getId()) {
        $page2->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')->save();
    } else {
        $page->setTitle('Page 2')
            ->setIdentifier('page2')
            ->setIsActive(true)
            ->setPageLayout('1column')
            ->setStores(array(0))
            ->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')
            ->save();
    }

    $page3 = $this->_pageFactory->create()->load('page3', 'identifier');
    if ($page3->getId()) {
        $page3->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')->save();
    } else {
        $page->setTitle('Page 3')
            ->setIdentifier('page3')
            ->setIsActive(true)
            ->setPageLayout('1column')
            ->setStores(array(0))
            ->setContent('<h1>This is it!</h1>')
            ->save();
    }
```

Comment: That's almost what I did, except in your else statements you are missing the numbers on the $page variable.Thanks!